# NSTableView load data

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I'm new to Mac OS development. I'm trying to load data from dataSource by implement

```
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, dataCellFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSCell? {}
```

But the cell seems to keep reloading while my mouse cursor is moving over the cell.
The type of cells in first column is all `NSButtonCell`, second one is `NSPopupButtonCell`, third one is `NSTextfieldCell`

[image]

For summary, my question is:
How to load data properly in my case? I find there are several ways to load data like `func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?`.

Comment: The cell-based `NSTableView` is obsolete since Lion, and it's recommended to use the view-based `NSTableView` instead. It's possible that you might see better behavior if you move to the modern view-based table view.

Comment: `tableView(_:dataCellFor:row:)` is a delegate method, not a datasource method. If you stick with a cell based table view (not recommended but it is still supported) then use `tableView(_:objectValueFor:row:)`.

Comment: Read [Table View Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: @CharlesSrstka But there are lots of good cells I can drag in the storyboard. How to use them then? Could you recommend me some tutorials?

Comment: @Willeke Got it. Thank you buddy.